# How To Validate a Devexpress Textbox inside an Devexpress Gridview in Javasacript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, aspxgridview

i am not able to figure out why the focusout validation that uses the assigned regex is not working in the devex textbox. when i am using the textbox out of the grid it starts working as required. Kindly suggest the solution.

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "InYear";
            column.Caption = "In Year";
            column.Width = 100;
            column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.TextBox;
            column.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending; // Default
            column.SortIndex = 1;
            column.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            var txtProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as TextBoxProperties;
            txtProperties.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            txtProperties.MaxLength = 4;
            txtProperties.DisplayFormatInEditMode = true;
            txtProperties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
            txtProperties.ValidationSettings.ValidateOnLeave = true;
            txtProperties.ValidationSettings.RegularExpression.ValidationExpression = @"\d{4}";
            txtProperties.ValidationSettings.RegularExpression.ErrorText = "Expected format is: YYYY";
            txtProperties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = String.Format("function (s, e) {{ OnValueChanged(s, e, '{0}', {1}); }}", "InYear", "0");
            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
            {
                if (!(bool)DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "ReadOnly"))
                {
                    Html.DevExpress().TextBox(txtSettings =>
                    {

                        txtSettings.Name = "txtInYear_" + c.KeyValue.ToString();
                        txtSettings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                        txtSettings.Properties.MaxLength = 4;
                        txtSettings.Properties.DisplayFormatInEditMode = true;
                        txtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ValidateOnLeave = true;
                        txtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ValidationGroup = c.KeyValue.ToString();
                        txtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RegularExpression.ValidationExpression = @"[0-9]{4}";
                        txtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RegularExpression.ErrorText = "Expected format is: YYYY";
                        txtSettings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = String.Format("function (s, e) {{ OnValueChanged(s, e, '{0}', {1}); }}", c.Column.FieldName, c.KeyValue);
                    }).Bind(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, c.Column.FieldName)).Render();


                }
                else
                    Html.DevExpress().Label(lblSettings =>
                    {
                        lblSettings.Name = "lblInYear_" + c.KeyValue.ToString();
                        lblSettings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                    }).Bind(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, c.Column.FieldName).ToString()).Render();
            });
        });
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

EDIT : I am using a button out of the gridview to trigger the update command. How can i trigger only validate event of the EditRow. Please view attached image.

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle i got the following answer :

- Assign a validation group property to the nested controls as below

  txtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ValidationGroup = c.KeyValue.ToString();
- Iterate through the keyvalues on client side and call the devexpress validate function **ASPxClientEdit.ValidateEditorsInContainer** as following, **i** represent validation group name

  var isValid =!ASPxClientEdit.ValidateEditorsInContainer(GridName.GetMainElement(), i)

My approach might not be the best but it helped me a lot, i think this would also be helpful for others having the same issue.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

When do you need to validate the TextBox? In browser mode or when editing? Currently your TextBox is required when you edit a row. Try to set the IsRequired property for your TextBox in the template as well.

```
txtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
```

It should work.

[image]

Comment: hi,That only works when the textbox is empty. if it contains invalid data is doesn't show error.Actually the default view contains a textbox that is always editable inside a grid-view. the save function is done by an another button by an ajax request .

Comment: It works fine for me. I've attached a screenshot to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this thread - [MVC GridView - Client validation in default EditForm](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q462474).

> In case if you are working with ajax form then i suggest you use
>   built-in validation instead:[GridView - How to use Microsoft
>   validation with an AJAX form to validate the Model properties on the
>   client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q405205.aspx).

More References:
[GridView - How to enable the client-side validation in the Edit Form](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q462474) 
[How to correctly enable Model, Unobtrusive or jQuery Client validation](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA20014)
[Client Validation in MVC3 with Gridview Template Form](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q365189)